# How to add additional column types in Windows Explorer's column quick menu permanently?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, column

I want to add some useful column types in the quick menu of Windows Explorer to not go through very long and bothersome process of scrolling through thousands of types in `Choose Details` window.

I want some items from this list:

[image]

To be permanently fixed in this list:

[image]

In every folder type in the system. Is this possible to do? I'm sure there must be some registry setting that lists the default ones like `Date`, `Type`, `Size`, etc.

Comment: **Each** folder type, e.g., Documents, General items, Music, Pictures and Videos, must have fields set. Those fields will always be displayed for that type folder.